# Convert an array into an argument list

Tags: c#, parameter-passing

A `DateTime` constructor requires 6 arguments:

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 1, 1, 6, 32, 0);
```

Now, I have

```
int[] dr = new int[]{2008, 1, 1, 6, 32, 0};
```

How can I "convert" that array into the argument list - something like `DateTime date1 = new DateTime(dr);` ?

Comment: `new DateTime(dr[0],dr[1],dr[2]....)`?

Comment: this is something that you can easily find the answer for if you do a simple google search on `new DateTime` does google work from you current region

Comment: I don't understand the downvoting/votes to close here: it is clear that OP *knows* the proper signature of the constructor; he just wants to know if there is a way to "unfold" an array into six individual parameters. The fact that C# does not provide any such "magic" is not enough to vote down the question.

Comment: And how on earth is this question "off-topic"?

Comment: How can a question relating to constructing code be 'off topic' here? Clearly an answer can be - as eminently illustrated here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do it like that, because the constructor does not take an array; it takes six individual parameters. A straightforward approach of breaking array apart manually should work, though:

```
var date1 = new DateTime(dr[0], dr[1], dr[2], dr[3], dr[4], dr[5]);
```

If you have to do it in multiple spots in your code, make a helper method to hide this code:

```
static class DateHelper {
    public DateTime MakeFromComponents(int[] dr) {
        return new DateTime(dr[0], dr[1], dr[2], dr[3], dr[4], dr[5]);
    }
}
...
var date1 = DateHelper.MakeFromComponents(dr);
```

Comment: Thank you very much; I do have to do it many times. The helper method 'helps'.

Comment: This is unlike some other (dynamic) languages where an array (or rather, a tuple) can be passed straight as an argument list.

Answer (score 1):

Some things are not that hard as it seems...

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(dr[0], dr[1], dr[2], dr[3], dr[4], dr[5])
```

Simply pass in every item in the array into the appropriate constructor parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(dr[0], dr[1], dr[2], dr[3], dr[4], dr[5]);
```